# Calling Resolve function goes to Reject function in JavaScript Promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I have the following code:

```
return new Promise (function (resolve,reject) {
        if (this.ImageData && averageColor) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status == 200) {
                    console.log("Image found");
                    resolve(xhr.response);
                }else {
                    console.log("Image not found");
                    reject();
                }
            }
            xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8765/color/'+averageColor, true);
            xhr.send(null);
        }
        else {
            reject();
        }
    });
```

The function that calls this code is as follows:

```
var v =  tile.getImage(tile.getColorAverage());
        v.then(function (value) {
            console.log("laughing");
        }).catch(function () {
           console.log("Catch called");
        });
```

The issue is in my promise I can see that it is going in that if condition and getting the response from the server correctly (because of the console.log). However, on the other side, it doesn't go into 'then' bit of promise at all (not even once). It goes to the reject one for some reason. I am going nuts as I can see it executes the bit which is supposed to resolve it but I don't get anything in then. Any help would be much appreciated.

Edited:

Now I just ran it once. And here is my console.log trace. Now even more confused:

[image]

Comment: What are you expecting `this` to be within `Promise` resolver function?

Comment: can you put a console .log before both reject calls - just to debug

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status == 200) {
        console.log(xhr.response);
        resolve(xhr.response);
    }else {
        reject();
    }
}
```

The thing about onreadystatechange is, it gets called MULTIPLE times

The thing about promise resolution is that once rejected or resolved, it can not be rejected or resovled again

The first time onreadystatechange gets called, the status would be 1, not 4 ... so you reject

you should only reject if status is 4 and (DONE) AND status != 200

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        if(xhr.status == 200) {
            console.log(xhr.response);
            resolve(xhr.response);
        } else {
            reject();
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, use onload/onerror - though you still need to check for status == 200 in onload

```
xhr.onload= function () {
    if(xhr.status == 200) {
        console.log(xhr.response);
        resolve(xhr.response);
    } else {
        reject();
    }
}


xhr.onerror= function () {
    reject();
}
```

> as a side note about something that works but looks wrong

```
return new Promise (function (resolve,reject) {
    if (this.ImageData && averageColor) {
```

> `this` inside the promise constructor callback could be `window`, or it even could even be `undefined` in strict mode - you need to fix that code before it causes issues down the track

Comment: Substituting `load` event for `readystatechange` event should solve issue, yes?

Comment: yes, but then `onerror` should also be handled - and `onload` still needs to check for stats == 200

Comment: You do not address the issue of `this` within `Promise` constructor

Comment: that's not part of the question, I haven't even shown that part of the code! your answer doesn't address the incorrect assumptions about `onreadystatechange` - so ...

Comment: That is part of the Question. It is in the `javascript` at text of Question. Not sure what you mean by "so"? All of the answers are not addressing all elements of the Question.

Comment: Oh please, it's in the code, it's clearly misguided, but I can only make assumptions about that

Comment: @guest271314 - wouldn't be window in strict mode - so you're assumption is flawed

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Though would not reference the object OP is expecting and would evaluate to `false` at `if` condition; that is what was attempting to convey.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are having this issue is that `onreadystatechange` is called multiple times before the request completes and before it is DONE you will get your `else` condition which calls `reject`. You should only reject if `DONE` AND `xhr.status != 200`. Here is an example:

```
if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
    if (xhr.status == 200) {
        resolve(xhr.response);
    } else {
        reject();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` within `Promise` constructor is `window`, unless specifically set to a different value. `this.ImageData` would evaluate to `false` without setting `this` to the object that has `.ImageData` as a property at call to `new Promise()`.

Substitute reference to object that has property `ImageData` for `this.ImageData` within `Promise` constructor resolver function.

For example

```
function resolver(resolve, reject) {

}

new Promise(resolver.bind(/*object that has `.ImageData` as property*/))
```

Also, substitute `load` event for `readystatechange` event and include `error` event handler for `XMLHttpRequest` object.

Comment: Thanks for that. That doesn't solve the issue. It is calling the resolve function in onreadystatechange function (I can see that with console.log). However, it is now showing up in .then

Comment: @fur866 _"However, it is now showing up in .then"_ Not sure what you mean?

Comment: the fact that `console.log(xhr.response);` is being output means that (however misguided) BOTH if conditions are TRUE - so there should be no reject called

Comment: `this` could be `undefined` - not in this case, but assuming it is `window` is just as big an assumption as the original code has made

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, you are correct. Suggested explicitly setting `this` at Answer. Your Answer now addresses both issues.